# ActiveAdmin 0.4.3 Rails 3.2.3 Upgrade Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've upgraded ActiveAdmin from 0.2.2 to 0.4.3 and Rails from 3.0.0 to 3.2.3. I called  "rails generate active_admin:assets" as part of the ActiveAdmin upgrade process. I get the error below when I try to access the ActiveAdmin root directory (http://localhost:3000/admin). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-13 10:31:51 -0700
Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
Geokit is using the domain: localhost
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered /home/js/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeadmin-0.4.3/app/views/active_admin/dashboard/index.html.arb (77.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 86ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `destroy_admin_user_session_path' for #):
    1: render view_factory.dashboard_page

Full trace here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=W4bzay3t

config/initializers/active_admin.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.site_title = "SiteName"
  config.default_namespace = :admin
  config.authentication_method = :admin_user?
  config.current_user_method = :current_user
end
```

Comment: Can you add the code from your dashboard or comment it out and see if the issues persist? (EDIT: Nevermind, your answer is posted below I believe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your config block:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do | config | 
...
  config.logout_link_path = :signout_path
...
end
```

Cheers.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get this error now:

NoMethodError in Admin/dashboard#index

Showing /home/js/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeadmin-0.4.3/app/views/active_admin/dashboard/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `destroy_user_session_path' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::HeaderRenderer:0x0000000547e208>

Comment: run... rake routes | grep user ... and see if you can't find the appropriate path to configure here.

Comment: Ok. So @JeffAncel led me on the right path. Instead of rake routes | grep user, I ran rake routes | grep session. I then realized I have a /signout route defined that calls the Session::Destroy action. So I updated my ActiveAdmin initializer with `config.logout_link_path = :signout_path` and it works! Thanks a lot @JeffAncel!!!

Answer (score 0):

This will work if rake routes show this

signout     /signout(.:format)  sessions#destroy

Hope this help

ActiveAdmin.setup do | config | 
...
  config.logout_link_path = :signout_path
...
end